# Weighted randomness. How could I give more weight to rows that have just been added to the database?

Tags: php, sql, random

I'm retrieving 4 random rows from a table. However, I'd like it such that more weight is given to rows that had just been inserted into the table, without penalizing older rows much.

Is there a way to do this in PHP / SQL?

Comment: Select top 4 and Order rows by id desc, it will give you the latest rows first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think an agreeable solution would be to use an asymptotic function (1/x) in combination with weighting.

The following has been tested:

```
SELECT *, (Rand()*10 + (1/(max_id - id + 1))) AS weighted_random 
FROM tbl1 
ORDER BY weighted_random 
DESC LIMIT 4
```

If you want to get the max_id within the query above, just replace max_id with:

```
(SELECT id FROM tbl1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
```

**Examples:**

Let's say your max_id is 1000 ...

For each of several ids I will calculate out the value:

1/(1000 - id + 1) , which simplifies out to 1/(1001 - id):

*id: 1000*

1/(1001-1000) = 1/1  = 1

*id: 999*

1/(1001-999) = 1/2   = .5

*id: 998*

1/(1001-998) = 1/3   = .333

*id: 991*

1/(1001-991) = 1/10  = .1

*id: 901*

1/(1001-901) = 1/100 = .01

The nature of this 1/x makes it so that only the numbers close to max have any significant weighting.

You can see a graph of + more about asymptotic functions here:

http://zonalandeducation.com/mmts/functionInstitute/rationalFunctions/oneOverX/oneOverX.html

Note that the right side of the graph with positive numbers is the only part relevant to this specific problem.

**Manipulating our equation to do different things:**

(Rand()*a + (1/(b*(max_id - id + 1/b))))

I have added two values, "a", and "b"... each one will do different things:

The larger "a" gets, the less influence order has on selection. It is important to have a relatively large "a", or pretty much *only* recent ids will be selected.

The larger "b" gets, the more quickly the asymptotic curve will decay to insignificant weighting.  If you want more of the recent rows to be weighted, I would suggest experimenting with values of "b" such as: .5, .25, or .1.

The 1/b at the end of the equation offsets problems you have with smaller values of b that are less than one.

**Note:**

This is not a very efficient solution when you have a large number of ids (just like the other solutions presented so far), since it calculates a value for each separate id.

Comment: `(Rand()*10 + (1/(max_id - id + 1)))` <- can you describe exactly wht this does? Also, would increasing the "10" here make it more likely that older rows are retrieved, or is it the other way around?

Comment: @oxo: Just added some explanations and examples above.  Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: Your explanation needs to be upvoted a million times. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @oxo: :D.  Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *, (RAND() / id) AS o FROM your_table ORDER BY o LIMIT 4
```

This will order by `o`, where as `o` is `some random integer between 0 and 1` / `id`, which means, the older your row, the lower it's `o` value will be (but still in random order).

Comment: I'm  not sure I fully understand. I currently have it as `"SELECT  myTable.* FROM myTable WHERE status=1 and ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 4"` - how could this be modified?

Comment: Okay, I guess you have a primary incremental key (e.g. "id"). Now use the following query instead: `"SELECT myTable.*, (RAND() / myTable.id) AS o FROM myTable WHERE status=1 ORDER BY o LIMIT 4"`. (btw, you typed "... and ORDER ...", I guess that's just a typo?).

Comment: This is great. Thanks a lot. If I want to tweak it such that the oldest rows are not penalized so much, what could I do?

Comment: You could try replacing `(RAND() / id)` with `(RAND() * 2 / id)`. This gives some more weight to the `RAND()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
... ORDER BY (RAND() + 0.5 * id/maxId)
```

This will add half of the `id/maxId` ration to the random value. I.e. for the newest entry `0.5` is added (as `id/maxId = 1`) and for the oldest entry nothing is added.

Similarly you can also implement other weighting functions. This depends on how exactly you want to weight the values.